# WCF Hosted in IIS 7.0 Binding Issue

Tags: wcf-binding

I have hosted a WCF Service on IIS7 by creating a WCFService Application Project Type.

In WCF Service Solution, there are two Project. **1) Actual **WCFService**** **and 2) **WCFService Application**** for hosting it in IIS7.0

1) Actual WCFService Project.  **app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="DHDocuments.DService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                  contract="DHDocuments.IDService" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
           <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/DHDocuments/DService/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

**2) WCFService Application web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="DHDocuments.DService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="" 
                  name="basic" 
                  contract="DHDocuments.IDService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In the IIS its being hosted. Its available at **`http://localhost:2004/DService.svc`**

Now Coming to the WCF Consuming Project,

I have added a Service Reference by Pointing to the **`http://localhost:2004/DService.svc`**. In my WCF Consuming client project this is the **app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:2004/DService.svc" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="basic1" 
                contract="WCFDHService.IDService"
                name="basic" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basic1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
                 openTimeout="00:01:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                 messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" 
                 transferMode="Buffered"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192"
                        maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" 
                       proxyCredentialType="None"
                       realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" 
                     algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>       
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

- **This now complains:**

**The binding at system.serviceModel/bindings/basicHttpBinding does not have a configured binding named 'basic1'. This is an invalid value for bindingConfiguration**

**

Can someone point what is being missed?

There is no problem when I have utilised wcf service directly by debug mode, without hosting it in IIS. I am sure, the binding config is getting error.

Comment: Just a quick note to point out that the first config file is irrelevant in this case, as the first project (Based on the comments in the config file) is a class library - the config file in that project is not used.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have configured your services for metadata discovery with a mex endpoint:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

Another endpoint in the service configuration is defined as wsHttpBinding:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="DHDocuments.IDService" >
```

I am guessing since mex is enabled the client proxy will generate a wsdl, however, you need to specify https if using transport security. Or add a endpoint for **basicHttpBinding** in your wcf service.

It seems like you are trying to access your service in the client proxy using a basicHttpBinding configuration but the service is not configured to accept or listen for such.

Comment: The first config file is part of a WCF class library project (note the comments in the config file), so anything in that config is ignored, as the library will use the config file for the calling assembly.

Comment: I would try putting the <client> section after the <bindings> section and see if there is a load order issue in the configuration.